# How to import date fields using CSV file?

Tags: 7, datetime, importing-exporting

I'm trying to import few nodes using feeds CSV file. I'm able to import some of the fields but I'm unable to import CCK **date** fields.

I have tried feeds module with `uc_feeds_product_importer`.

**How can I import date fields?**

Comment: what format is your CSV date field? AFAIK Drupal only supports unix timestamps

Comment: I tried with following formats on csv.

    `2012-04-17 00:00:00`, 
    `13 April 2013`and etc, but nothing works after importing

Comment: check out this thread perhaps it will help http://drupal.org/node/722740 otherwise only other thing I can think of is try to convert your dates to Unix timestamps (something like 1353353096) which is how Drupal stores dates for nodes and user changes etc.

Comment: @AnAnD please use Edit link to provide details. Details in comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the feeds importer. I deleted the existing importer and created a new importer with new mappings, then all the date fields started working as normal.

The date format I use in the csv file is: `23-Apr-12`

Comment: don't forget to clear the site cache once.

Comment: For me the date format "2013-08-14 10:59:58" has always worked!