# Unable to import date from csv with Feeds module

Tags: feeds, datetime, importing-exporting

I have a simple csv file I'm trying to import with feeds.  Most of the fields are going in just fine, but the dates are failing.  And after following the process through in a debugger, I cannot see why this fails - ***the date exists when Feeds saves the node, so why does this fail?***.

[image: screenshot of debugger shows that entity has date information immediately after entitySaved is called]
Above: This screenshot of my debugger shows that entity has date information immediately after entitySaved is called.  I cannot detect anything unusual about the object format - looks kosher.  The date was added as the `field_deadline_proposals:end`. A date can be a range, so I assume this is the proper way to save a single date (non-range).

[image: screenshot of database immediately after node save]
Above: This is a screenshot of the database table for field_deadline_proposals immediately after node save.  Node 258 does not have the information I expect.

This is the relevant excerpt from my csv doc, with headers:

```
id,rfp_num,description,title,published,rfp_filename,response_deadline,QA_deadline,mod_date,create_date
4,034-009  Robinson Pkwy,"Robinson Pkwy -Walkthru 6/22/09  9:30am.  Log onto the website for more information. Due date has been moved to 7/6/09  11:00am",TRUE,RFP_034-009  Robinson Pkwy_034-009_doc.pdf,7-6-2009 11:00,29-06-2009 13:00,7-1-2009 13:50,19-06-2009 9:29
```

My dates are currently in `d-m-yyyy hh:mm` format, which seems to work just fine and [was recommended in this related post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70783/date-import-using-csv).  Frankly, I don't think the date format it much of an issue - I have had success with other formats, including using feeds_tamper to convert the date to UNIX timestamps.  In all cases, though, the save fails, so I suspect some other issue :-/

Answer (score 2):

Got it.  Turns out that adding a new mapping that used the same date field with the `Deadling for Proposals: start` target solved things.

This wasn't particularly intuitive for me, so maybe this will be helpful for someone else too.

[image]