# Importing dates TO and FROM using Feeds module

Tags: feeds

I'm wanting to import some content to my drupal site. One of the fields for this new content type is a date field. The date actually has both to and from fields and in fact the nodes I will be importing have a start and end date...I've read about importing using the Feeds module (here for example: [How to import date fields using CSV file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70783/date-import-using-csv)...but) I haven't been able to find any material on importing a date range (for example, an event. The event begins on August 4, 2015 and ends on August 6). What would be the format for that?

I'm imagining something like MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY. Does anyone know the preferred format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I discovered these can be handled by specifying the Date: Start and Date: End fields in the Feeds importer itself; sweet.